# validate number on paste in inputtext

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input field in which any user can paste only numbers but if the string contains any alphabet then it will not allow to paste.

i am currently using this code but its not work;

```
$('[id$=CRRId]').bind('paste', function(e) { 
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
if(charCode != 45 && (charCode != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
{
return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
});
```

Please suggest correct code, Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: replace 'paste' with 'keyup'

Comment: I have to add validation on paste event not on keypress

Comment: Why not just use an `<input type="number">`?

Comment: @Abhitalks `type="number"` comes with spinners and does not have max length. This is 1 reason, I prefer `type="tel"`

Comment: well you would need to look at the data in the clipboard, not the keycode.

Comment: @DheerajPandey See the question I linked when closing.  The accepted answer shows how to remove everything but numbers, and another answer shows you need to bind the paste event.